# Site to find out which card to use for specific purchases

Tags: united-states, credit-card, reward-program

I've got a couple of large purchases coming up (thousands of dollars). I plan to use credit card for that - I have the money for it, but various credit cards have 1% to 5% cashback bonuses, and with big purchases this can add up to a substantial sum, so I want to use it. Basically, I'd want to purchase it with the card, get the rewards, then next month when the bill comes pay it off from savings (which means I don't care about rates, etc.)

Now the question is which card to use for it. So does anybody know a site that, given the nature of the purchase (i.e. travel, home improvement, grocery, electronics, etc.) and date, would tell me which card it is best to use - taking into account all the rotating categories, temporary offers, etc.? There are a lot of sites that allow to choose based on monthly spending, features of the card, etc. but most of them do not take into account rotating categories and one-time purchases at specific time.

Comment: Its a problem... Some actually allow choosing the reward category per customer per quarter. I wrote about the US Bank card recently in my blog

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is just to pick a card that gives you the best (highest) rewards without charging you an annual or other fees (or the lowest annual or other fees). As you are looking to pay off the full balance by the due date you won't have to worry about the interest rate but just make sure you get an interest free period.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the cards you already have. If you don't have enough room on the best card, then ask for a credit increase.

You have to keep in mind that some of the programs have a maximum amount you can charge to get the bonus cash back amount.

Others have a graduated plan where the first few thousand dollars are at a lower cash back rate.

If you do decide to get a new card, make sure you get a large enough credit limit or the work to get a new card was for naught.

I would start with [bankrate.com](http://www.bankrate.com) to research cards.

Comment: It's not a question of room. It's a question of maximizing rewards. As far as I can see bankrate does not have current data on rotating categories.